# Elasticsearch painless get string field (which contains XML) into a variable

Tags: xml, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

I'm trying to parse an Elasticsearch string field (named `Request.Body`) which contains XML. This field contains a SOAP request string, like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="myURL">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:find>
      <token>myData</token>
      <login>myData</login>
      <language>myData</language>
      <search>myData</search>
      <contains>false</contains>
    </ns1:find>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My goal is to extract the value of the `search` tag in a scripted field (in Kibana) using the painless language.

I tried this :

```
def field = doc['Request.Body'].value;
if (field != null) {
  def matcher = /<search>(.*)<\/search>/.matcher(field);
  if (matcher.find()) {
    return matcher.group(1);
  }
  return "No match";
}
return "No field";
```

This code always returns `No match`.

To debug, I try to return the value of `doc['Request.Body'].value`, in this example, it returns only `1.0` instead of my full XML.

I also tried to concat the values of the `values` List in this object with that code :

```
def field = doc['Request.Body'].getValues().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(""));
if (field != null) {
  def matcher = /<search>(.*)<\/search>/.matcher(field);
  if (matcher.find()) {
    return matcher.group(1);
  }
  return "No match";
}
return "No field";
```

Now, the `field` variable is equals to the contains of XML tags values, but I lose the XML tags, so I can't extract my data with the regex and like the first script, it returns always `No match`.

So my question is, how to get the full XML value of my field in a variable in my script ? Why Elasticsearch is "parsing" my XML ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old topic, but just run into the same problem. I was able to solve it using the field definition this way:

```
def field = params._source.Request.Body;
```

This code can extract the relevant information from a sting field:

```
def field = params._source.message;
if (field != null) {
def matcher = /<decisionText>(.*)<\/decisionText>/.matcher(field);
if (matcher.find()) {
return matcher.group(1);
}
return "No match";
}
return "No field";
```

In my case the data is in the "message" field